# Format vector into autoregressive matrix

Tags: r, matrix, formatting, dataframe

Given a numeric vector `x` and a lag `t`, i need and efficient way of producing an 'auto correlated' matrix, where each row is x(i), x(i - 1), x(i - 2), ..., x(i - t). Example:

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(6)
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684
```

Using x and t = 3:

```
M = autoreg.format(x, 3)
              x         x1         x2         x3
[1,]  1.5952808 -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286
[2,]  0.3295078  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808
[3,] -0.8204684 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078
```

Currently i'm using the code below, which works fine. I'm just curious to know if there's a faster or more concise way of doing this:

```
autoreg.format = function(x, t) {

  y = tail(x, -t)
  x = matrix(t(sapply(head(1:length(x), -t), function(v){x[seq(v, length = t)]})), ncol = t)
  data = cbind(y, x)
  colnames(data) = c("x", paste("x", 1:t, sep = ""))
  data
}
```

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = 3
ac <- embed(x,t+1)
```

Will do the trick.  It's in a different order than your `autoreg.format` function, though.  You can label the columns, like so:

```
colnames(ac) <- paste0("X",t:0)
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't have a clue that `embed` exists! It's much more faster than my implementation (for large datasets anyway).

Comment: Yes, i think changing your code to `t = 3; embed(x, t + 1)` is easier to understand the function, given my post.